# What query creates a trigger to generate composite primary key with two fk?

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle10g, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to write a command to create a trigger that generates the composite primary key. This pk is in turn based on two fk.

I'll write example tables to be more specific.

(Table I'm working on)

```
CREATE TABLE DB.MESSAGE (
  TEXT      CLOB         NOT NULL,
  SUBJECT   VARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
  MSG_TYPE  NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
  MAIL_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
)
;

ALTER TABLE DB.MESSAGE ADD CONSTRAINT MSG_PK PRIMARY KEY ( MSG_TYPE, MAIL_ID ) ;

ALTER TABLE DB.MESSAGE ADD
(
    CONSTRAINT MESSAGE_TYPE_ID_FK
    FOREIGN KEY ( MSG_TYPE )
        REFERENCES DB.TYPES ( TYPE_ID )
);

ALTER TABLE DB.MESSAGE ADD
(
    CONSTRAINT MESSAGE_MAIL_FK
    FOREIGN KEY ( MAIL_ID )
        REFERENCES DB.EML_MAIL ( MAILTO_ID )
);
```

(Referenced tables)

```
CREATE TABLE DB.TYPES (
  TYPE_ID    NUMBER(13)        NOT NULL, 
  NAME       VARCHAR2(10)       NOT NULL
)
;

CREATE TABLE DB.MAIL (
  MAIL_ID    NUMBER(10)        NOT NULL, 
  MAIL       VARCHAR2(350)       NOT NULL
)
;
```

My query so far

```
create or replace
TRIGGER DB.TRG_MESSAGE_ID
BEFORE  INSERT ON DB.MESSAGE

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF INSERTING THEN
  IF :NEW."MSG_ID" IS NULL THEN
    SELECT DB.TYPES.TYPE_ID ??????
    INTO :NEW."MSG_ID" FROM dual;
  END IF;
 END IF;
END;
```

EDIT: So the thinking behind this question was that there would be a separated column with a concatenations of both keys that compose the composite key. 
A friend told me this is wrong, you just put both fields as pk and that's that. Is this true?

Comment: Are you trying to provide a default value for type_id if one is not provided?  And using the trigger to pull it from a table instead of hardcoding a default?

Comment: Sorry for lack of detail. It's Oracle 10g

Comment: Ken, I think yes. the trigger is for insert. When a new element is inserted he generates the id from the two columns that also are fk.

Comment: A foreign key references something you know about. Not knowing what the foreign key is indicates your data is not well defined. You could select from a sequence and insert a row into the TYPES table. But you'd probably end up with a lot of dubious rows in both tables.

Comment: @redcayuga you do get these cases, and they are not ill-defined data, if you are implementing a lot of biz logic in materialized columns.  I use the strategy regularly.

Comment: @Kotoko is the question then where to get that default value from?